# Does a White Mage Arcanist need to Use Magic Device to activate a Wand of Cure Light Wounds?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, archetype

I was tasked with building the third character of a 3 person party, and make that character fill in all the missing holes. The other two characters are a Hunter specializing in bows and a Sword and Board Barbarian.

I found [White Mage archetype Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo---arcanist-archetypes/white-mage) because it allows me to spontaneously cast heal spells and still gain the battle control spells of a wizard.

Cure Light Wounds, while I can spontaneously cast it, is not part of my spell list. So, do I need to perform a Use Magic Device check on a wand of Cure Light Wounds, even though I can cast the spell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you must make a UMD check. The relevant text is this (emphasis added):

> At 1st level, a white mage can expend 1 point from her arcane reservoir to use one of her spell slots to cast a cure spell (any spell with "cure" in its name) from the cleric spell list **as if it were on her spell list** and prepared.

It's never really on your spell list; you just get to act like it is in a certain limited circumstance. But if you're not expending that point, you don't get that benefit.

You can probably argue that expending the point should allow you to use a single charge of the wand without making a check, but strictly speaking that's a bit of a houserule, since the RAW is limited to using spell slots. Perfectly reasonable, balance-wise, but not really part of the text.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was thinking in the first place, I just wanted a second opinion. I am away that the DM could decide that I am allowed, just wanted to understand the rules that governed it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much you care about the RAW.

By RAW, you don't have the spell on your spell list.  You can cast it spontaneously "as if it were on [your] spell list", which means that it isn't actually on your spell list.  The RAW is pretty clear here: if a spell isn't on your list, you need UMD to cast it.

However, it's a totally reasonable houserule to say that since you can cast Cure spells, you can use those spells out of magic items.  Especially given that you're in a 3-person group with limited access to healing, it might be a good thing for the game if you have slightly easier access to healing magic.  I would suggest asking your GM.

Comment: Keep in mind this has other ramifications, like being able to craft wands of it...

Comment: You can already make wands just by being able to cast the spell.  The crafting rules say "(although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed)".  If you can meet a prereq by having a magic item cast the spell, you can certainly meet it by casting the spell yourself.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my comment. Yes, IF you allow them to use it from an item, then they can make magic items of it.  My point is that usually you cannot ("Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item's creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed).") so by letting them use it on an item, they are also unlocking being able to craft it as an item, which is yet more increase.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my misunderstanding.  I'm saying that if being able to cast a spell from an item lets you make a magic item, then being able to cast a spell _without_ a magic item works exactly as well in meeting requirements.  The important part is that you can cast the spell, not where you got the ability to cast the spell.

Comment: *Maybe*, again depending on how RAWcore you ware.